# Altair facet charts save individual image

Tags: python, image, facet, altair

How to split Altair .facet chart into individual images with option to save each one.

is it possible to save individual images when using .facet?

provided basic example of .facet chart with image save option for whole group.
[image]

(Screenshot from https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#faceted-charts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only save full charts; there is no mechanism to individually save subpanels of a single chart.

As a workaround, you can re-create these subpanels as single charts. Here is one possible approach using a conditional opacity:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris()

chart = alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=160,
    height=160
)

for species in ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']:
    chart.encode(
        opacity=alt.condition(
            f"datum.species == '{species}'", alt.value(1), alt.value(0)
        )
    ).display()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response, my example may have been a bit too basic. I've created control charts with upper, lower limits and rules for signals .i.e. run of 7 below mean. I've then layered these all together into a template chart and .facet to duplicate the chart for each department. Will this approach work for breaking the charts back down?

Comment: Yes, some adaptation of this approach should be suitable even in more complicated charts.