# Vertical faceted chart in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I need to create a faceted chart in altair. I am using the example given in this link (https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html) which places charts horizontally. The code is

```
import altair as alt

from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris.url
alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N',
    column='species:N'
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
)
```

Result - [image]

My question is if it is possible to get the same charts but vertically. The output required is similar to the one answered by @jakevdp for this question ([Altair facet charts save individual image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66315913/altair-facet-charts-save-individual-image)) but without the need to create separate charts.
Screenshot - [image]

Thanks

Comment: Just replace `column='species:N'` with `row='species:N'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just change column to row.

```
import altair as alt

from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris.url
alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N',
    row='species:N'
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
)
```